# How to make a specific amount of items in a list view?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a function that takes all the files from a folder and puts them into a list view:

```vb
Public Sub IMAEWDA()
    Dim imagelist1 As ImageList = New ImageList()

    Dim files As String()
    imagelist1.ImageSize = New Size(100, 100)

    files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\khale\OneDrive\Pictures\Screenshots")
    Try
        For Each f In files
            imagelist1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(f))
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    If imagelist1.Images.Count = 0 Then
        ListView1.Visible = False
    End If
    ListView1.SmallImageList = imagelist1
End Sub
```

But I have to make individual items for each image and I don't really think that is a convenient way to go, so I thought in the `For` Loop I could make a new item every time a file is detected, but I haven't been able to do that. I have tried adding an integer and each time a file is detected a new item come with the value of `+1` from the previous value, but no luck. Any answer would be fine, maybe even using another component other than `ImageList`s.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking for new files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015325/checking-for-new-files-in-a-folder)

Comment: Thanks, it gives me a few ideas but can I apply the same principle to a listview using the file system watcher?

Comment: The problem of detecting files as they appear has no relation to listviews or any other user controls. You have the mechanism that detects new files, so trigger your listview filling code when it tells you that a file has appeared.

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49022052/7444103) is ready to use. You just need to substitute the *register event to file logger* feature to an *add and remove from ListView* feature. You can also find some instructions on how the FileSysteWatcher works.